# Insert a % of total value into a pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have 3 companies A, B and C and their sales data for each quarter of 2018 divided into Computers and Printers categories.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Fiscal Quarter": ["FY18-Q1", "FY18-Q1", "FY18-Q1", "FY18-Q1", "FY18-Q1", "FY18-Q1",
                                      "FY18-Q2", "FY18-Q2", "FY18-Q2", "FY18-Q2", "FY18-Q2", "FY18-Q2",
                                      "FY18-Q3", "FY18-Q3", "FY18-Q3", "FY18-Q3", "FY18-Q3", "FY18-Q3",
                                      "FY18-Q4", "FY18-Q4", "FY18-Q4", "FY18-Q4", "FY18-Q4", "FY18-Q4"],
                   "Company": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C",
                               "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C",
                               "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C",
                               "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
                   "Category": ["Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers",
                                "Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers",
                                "Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers",
                                "Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers", "Computers", "Printers"],
                   "Sales": [300, 350, 1000, 700, 2500, 2800,
                             450, 200, 1100, 720, 2400, 2100,
                             600, 330, 850, 1200, 2400, 2000,
                             520, 400, 900, 700, 2000, 2200]})
```

https://github.com/currentlyunknown/sampledata/blob/master/sampledata.csv

I would like to see 'values' not only as a $ sales for each company, but also as a % comparison to the total sales during a quarter (A+B+C), so as an example for company A:

```
               FY18-Q1          FY18-Q2
Computers      300              450
Printers       350              400
```

**The desired output** would be something like this:

```
               FY18-Q1          FY18-Q2
Computers      300              450
               30%              40%
Printers       350              400
               25%              27%
```

So far I got to prepare a df with ['% of Total'] column for each company using this:

```
total = df.groupby(['Fiscal Quarter', 'Category']).sum().rename(columns={"Sales": "Total Sales"})

df = df.merge(total, on=['Fiscal Quarter', 'Category'])

df['% of Total'] = (df['Sales'] / df['Total Sales'])

df = df.drop(['Total Sales'], axis=1)
```

I create pivot tables to see the sales data of each company separately:

```
dfa = df[df['Company']=='A']

A = pd.pivot_table(
    dfa,
    index=['Category'],
    columns=['Fiscal Quarter'],
    values=['Sales', '% of Total'],
    aggfunc=np.sum
    ).reset_index()

A.columns = A.columns.droplevel([0])
A = A.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

But I end up with:

```
               FY18-Q1          FY18-Q2          FY18-Q1          FY18-Q2
Computers      300              450              30%              40%
Printers       350              400              25%              27%
```

Now, how do I pivot it in the desired way?

Comment: can you please provide some sample data frame for company A,B,C

Comment: https://github.com/currentlyunknown/sampledata/blob/master/sampledata.csv

Answer (score 0):

1. Calculate the total sum in a copy of the table (groupby + sum)
2. Merge two tables by the name of the company (you will get an additional total sales column)
3. Calculate % between the total sales and the exact Q sale
4. Pivot

Comment: Using this method I end up with duplicated columns for each Q, not combining values next to one another in rows.